# How to convert string to Datetime in AWS Quicksight using calculated field?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have the column values in the format 'YYYY Q' and want to convert it into datetime(YYYY-Q) format using calculated field.
e.g. '2021 3', '2022 4', '2020 1'

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the best as coding goes, but I believe QuickSight doesen't offer the possibility to have dates in quarter formats outside visualizations, but I think that you could have it working like so:

```
parseDate(
concat(split(string_date, ' ', 1), '-', 
    ifelse(split(string_date, ' ', 2) = '1', '01-01',
    ifelse(split(string_date, ' ', 2) = '2', '04-01',
    ifelse(split(string_date, ' ', 2) = '3', '07-01',
    '10-01')))), 
'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

This will return you a new date field with the starting date of each quarter. Then, in your visualizations you can set the date agregation to quarter.